# Error Deleting Child Entity in Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We are using EF6 database first with AspNet Identity. AspNetUsers is our table of customers. It extends AspNet IdentityUser. Each customer has many devices. The abbreviated table structures are

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] (
    [Id]                   NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Devices] (
    [DeviceID]     INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId]       NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Devices]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Devices_AspNetUsers] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]);
```

`CustomersContext OnModelCreating`specifies the relationship between AspNetUsers and Devices.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
.HasMany(e => e.Devices)
.WithRequired(e => e.User)
.HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId)
.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Device>()
.HasKey(e => e.DeviceId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Device>().Property(e => e.UserId)
.IsRequired()
.HasMaxLength(450);
```

The following code

```
var userDevices = user.Devices.ToList();
foreach (Device device in userDevices)
{
     user.Devices.Remove(device);
}

await customersContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

fails with the error

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UserId', table 'Customers.dbo.Devices'
```

That appears to be trying to remove the relationship without deleting the device. How do I delete a device using EF?

Comment: Is it possible for you to give us a bit of more context of the entire problem. What all I could get it that your database name is "Customers". You are using code first development methodology of entity framework. Can you give some detail of tables, their relationship and their schema involved? What is this aspNetUser thing? Also even after removing the devices one by one in foreach statement there is no commit for EF object which will push the changes towards DB. Is that a typo or deliberately removed for brevity.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @RBT. I have edited my question to include abbreviated table structures and the SaveChanges line that produces the error.

Comment: What is this ApplicationUser entity. Is it AspNetUsers only. And it is always more helpful if you can provide full table structures instead of abbreviated ones else people have to keep guessing. Although other columns might not be in use in your current query but still for the sake of completeness. Glad to see you are using asp.net identity in place of asp.net membership providers for your implementation.

Comment: @RBT ApplicationUser inherits from IdentityUser. It is the standard mechanism through which IdentityUser is extended. You can find many references on extending IdentityUser. This example is simplified for clarity. No other fields are relevant.

Comment: Is customersContext inherited from DbContext? There is nothing mentioned about user variable? How are  you deducing user variable? Also since you are using await keyword you must have created an async function to save DB changes. Can you please post the whole piece of code. It will be really helpful in debugging your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to delete the device. It is not possible to just remove it from the `Devices` list, as it cannot exist stand-alone by itself. It has a non-nullable foreign key (from column `UserId`) referencing AspNetUsers(`Id`) - deletion would break referential integrity.

To delete the device, add following statement inside `foreach` loop to successfully delete the devices associated with a user.

```
customersContext.Entry(device).State = EntityState.Deleted;
```

Another way would be to place following code inside `foreach` loop to delete the device directly from the device repository itself, instead of going through `Devices` navigation property available on `ApplicationUser` entity:

```
customersContext.Devices.Remove(device);
```

If you don't want to delete the records from the `Devices` table and just want to remove the relationship between `AspNetUsers` and all the `Devices` in one go, then you can assign `null` to the `navigation` property and save the changes. This will remove the relation between the entities without physically deleting the records from database.

```
user.Devices = null;
```